# Want to expand identity to multi projects (asp.net mvc5)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, share, asp.net-identity

I have 3 projects in a solution. And each project have different own url. I want to share authentication cookie in these projects. For example, there are each project's url.
(1) project 1 : localhost:2000
(2) project 2 : localhost:2001/Identity
(3) project 3 : localhost:2002/WebService

If I log-in localhost:2001/Identity and move to localhost:2000. I want then this page(localhost:2000)'s log-in status is 'log-in already'. 
But now, I have to log-in independently. Help me :(

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by single-sign-on(SSO).

please look into http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/current/reference/html/configuration-sso.html and some more for this.